# Windows 7 / ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3400 Drivers

Tags: windows-7, drivers, display

I have an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3400 Series display adapter in my IBM Thinkpad T400 running Windows 7 32-bit.  I've downloaded the newest Windows 7 drivers from ati.amd.com but the installation always fails with the error message:

"CATALYST Install Manager has stopped working"

Has anyone had any luck with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is quite easy:

- open a CMD-box with administrative privileges
- go to your ATI drivers, probably in a location similar to this one:

  ```
  C:\ATI\SUPPORT\8-10_vista32_dd_ccc_wdm_emu_69564\
  ```
- then go to the BIN (or BIN64 for Vista64) folder underneath
- type this command:

  ```
  atisetup.exe -Install -Output screen
  ```

  [image]

If all goes well the drivers will then install successfully. Do not forget to reboot your machine after installation!

Comment: I walked through your steps and rebooted and the display adapter was still showing an exclamation point in the device manager.  I told it to update the driver and allowed it to do it automatically and this time it found and installed the ATI driver which I downloaded.  After aanother reboot, it still shows an exclamation point in the device manager.  In the properties window, it also states that the driver was loaded but that it can not start.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I will have another look into it, as this should of worked

Comment: After uninstalling and removing the drivers files a second time, then reinstalling the ATI software as you stated, and rebooting at the end.  It now seems to be installed correctly.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: As an update to this question, there's now an updated driver listed on the ATI/AMD website: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but the CMD-box answer didn't work.

My problem was caused by the Visual C++ redistributables the Catalyst manager tries to install, this [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/961894) let me install the Catalyst manager correctly.